# Adding a SOAP header to a SOAPpy request

Tags: python, soappy

Does anyone know how to do this? I need to add a header of the form:

value1
    value2

Comment: try being more specific? what's your request and how you send it?

Answer (score 4):

As the question is phrased, it's hard to guess what the intention (or even the intended semantics) is. For setting headers, try the following:

```
import SOAPpy
headers = SOAPpy.Types.headerType()
headers.value1 = value2
```

or

```
[...]
headers.foo = value1
headers.bar = value2
```